# SQL Syntax help, MERGE GROUP BY for Datawarehouse Dimensions

Tags: sql, t-sql, syntax, data-warehouse

I have a TSQL code that I want to use to update/insert my dimension (SCD Type 1) from a source table, below is the code:

```
MERGE [dim].[CompanyTest] AS Target
USING [dbo].[DWUSD_LIVE] AS Source
    ON Target.Comp = Source.Comp
 WHEN MATCHED
    AND (ISNULL(Target.[Comp Name],'') <> ISNULL(Source.[Comp Name],'')
    OR ISNULL(Target.[Comp Description],'') <> ISNULL(Source.[Comp Description],'')
   )
THEN UPDATE SET
    [Comp Name] = Source.[Comp Name]
   ,[Comp Description] = Source.[Comp Description]
   ,LastUpdated = GetDate()
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (
        Comp
        ,[Comp Name]
        ,[Comp Description]
        ,LastUpdated
      ) VALUES (
         Source.Comp
        ,Source.[Comp Name]
        ,Source.[Comp Description]
        ,GetDate()
);
```

My source table has:

```
[COMP] [COMP NAME] [COMP DESCRIPTION]
1,100,MyCompany,Service Provider
1,100,MyCompany,Service Provider
1,100,MyCompany,Service Provider
2,200,MyCompany,Service Provider
2,200,MyCompany,Service Provider
2,200,MyCompany,Service Provider
2,200,MyCompany,Service Provider
```

When I run the above TSQL once, I get this in my dimension:

```
[COMP] [COMP NAME] [COMP DESCRIPTION]
1,100,MyCompany,Service Provider
1,100,MyCompany,Service Provider
1,100,MyCompany,Service Provider
2,200,MyCompany,Service Provider
2,200,MyCompany,Service Provider
2,200,MyCompany,Service Provider
2,200,MyCompany,Service Provider
```

The first issue is, when I try to re-run this I get:

**Msg 8672, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.**

I understand that I need to insert a "GROUP BY" into the statement, how can I do this so that I only get only the distinct rows back from the source table.

Then my Dimension should only have:

```
[COMP] [COMP NAME] [COMP DESCRIPTION]
1,100,MyCompany,Service Provider
2,200,MyCompany,Service Provider
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple.Use In USING statement derived table

```
MERGE [dim].[CompanyTest] AS Target
USING (
       SELECT DISTINCT *
       FROM [dbo].[DWUSD_LIVE]
       ) AS Source
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It works now, my final code looks like this:

```
MERGE [dim].[CompanyTest] AS Target
USING (
SELECT DISTINCT 
[COMP NAME],
[COMP DESCRIPTION],
[COMP]
FROM [dbo].[DWUSD_LIVE]
) AS Source
    ON Target.Comp = Source.Comp
 WHEN MATCHED
    AND (ISNULL(Target.[Comp Name],'') <> ISNULL(Source.[Comp Name],'')
    OR ISNULL(Target.[Comp Description],'') <> ISNULL(Source.[Comp Description],'')
   )
THEN UPDATE SET
    [Comp Name] = Source.[Comp Name]
   ,[Comp Description] = Source.[Comp Description]
   ,LastUpdated = GetDate()
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (
        Comp
        ,[Comp Name]
        ,[Comp Description]
        ,LastUpdated
      ) VALUES (
         Source.Comp
        ,Source.[Comp Name]
        ,Source.[Comp Description]
        ,GetDate()
);
```

I was so close!! Thanks :)